AOC Regulations and the relabelling of old Bordeaux
When very old Bordeaux wines are recorked at the chateau and perhaps relabelled, is this done in accordance with current or historical regulations ?
I sometimes see 19th Century vintages marked 'Appellation Pauillac Contrôlée' or similar when as I understand it the AOC wasn't introduced until 1936.
I asked ChatGPT and it responded that relabelling would have to follow current rules. When I queried this it changed its 'mind' and said of course pre-AOC wines could not be labelled Appellation Contrôlée.
I'd rather trust a human expert.

1st step - never ask ChatGPT anything and expect a correct answer. It has no intelligence - it is simply a statistical language model.
